# Select a Jekyll theme that is ready for drop-in use on Github Pages via `remote-theme` option

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm following the suggestion from [2017 blog post](https://github.blog/2017-11-29-use-any-theme-with-github-pages/) one can use any theme hosted on Github to build Github pages site, just by `remote-theme` tag.

I have a repo with just a README.md and _config.yml. I tried two themes and they failed in own way when added to `remote-theme`

- `remote-theme:poole/lanyon` showed some text but it was scarttered
- `remote-theme:mmistakes/minimal-mistakes` broke on build

I realise working via supported themes or building locally is safer, but maybe someone knows
popular Jekyll themes that work by `remote-theme` tag with minimal configuraton.

Answer (score -1):

The default theme for Github Pages is [primer](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer).

Try adding `_config.yml`:

```
remote-theme: pages-themes/primer
```

The behaviour is just like as if you started Github Pages without any special theme, however you can get access to some of [site config variables](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer#customizing).